Django Annotation: Convert time difference to whole number or decimal
I am trying to sum the hours user spent per day. I wanted to convert this into whole number or decimal to represent HOURS(e.g. 2, 6.5), to easily plot this to my chart. But the result of below code is in this format HH:mm:ss. Any one can help me with this?
day = Clocking.objects.filter(clockout__isnull=False, user=nid).annotate(date=TruncDate('clockin'))
      .values('date').annotate(total=Sum(F('clockout') - F('clockin'))).values('total')

Here is my models.py
class Clocking(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING)
    clockin = models.DateTimeField()
    clockout = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


Sorry for the lack of Django interpretation, you need TIMEDIFF between your clock in/out, wrapped in TIME_TO_SEC and them SUM those. ref fiddle

Based on Func using the sql functions TIMEDIFF and then TIME_TO_SEC, will return the seconds:
day = Clocking.objects.filter(clockout__isnull=False, user=nid).annotate(date=TruncDate('clockin'))
      .values('date').annotate(
    total=Sum(
        Func(
            Func(
                F('clockout'),F('clockin'), function='TIMEDIFF'),
            function='TIME_TO_SEC')
        )).values('total')


Answer based on many assumptions. Use with caution.

If you're using a database that has native support for duration field (Postgres or Oracle) then you can instead use the Extract database function. Otherwise you'll have to use your database's function like this or do some math in your queries.

Thanks for noting @AbdulAzizBarkat, If anyone wants MariaDB to have Interval as a type, please vote/watch (or implement) MDEV-12513 and there after it should be simple to provide Django integration.
